# Is it correct to say: “Let's have another person into the game”?

Tags: grammaticality

Let us assume that we are three friends playing bowling and we like to have a 4th player. Can we say: "Let's have another person into the game"?

I'm doubtful about the use of the word "into". Is this the correct word to use here.

Comment: Why do you ask about *this*? What makes you doubt this expression. Why do you think there is a problem here?  Have you been told this expression is wrong? Have you ever used this expression. Why are you asking about this *today*?

Comment: I am in doubt about the correctness of the grammar. That’s why I asked.

Comment: Why?  There are billions of expressions possible in English. Why are you asking about this one today?  What doubts do you have about the grammar?  Do you doubt the verb "have" (should it be has, or had?) Do you doubt the order of words? Do you doubt the prepostion "into"...... Why do *you* think there is a problem with this sentence?

Comment: Yes doubt about into. Or looking for a correct way to express this. As I explained in the context of my question this expression can arise in a game that we want to add another person. Is it wrong I asked this question in this Forum?

Comment: good so now you have a specific question. I'll edit that in.

Comment: Thank you James!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no phrasal verb "have (something) into" and you use the preposition "into" with verbs  indicating/that indicate motion. So this sentence doesn't work.

You can use the structure "Have (somebody) do (something)", meaning "cause (somebody) to do (something)".  This gives a sentence like:

> Let's have another person join the game.

There is also a phrasal verb "get into", so "Let's get another person into the game." is possible.  But there are other ways to express this, such as:

> Let's find a fourth player.

Many other possibilities exist.